# aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus' : execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, raspberrypi, c++

I am trying to build a C++ file with `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` for Raspberry Pi 3 64 bit and I am running this command :

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a53 test.cpp
```

But I am getting this error:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `aarch64-linux-gnu-g++` for C++ source? (and it's the corresponding `g++` cross-compiler package that provides cc1plus anyhow I think)

Comment: yess you are right I installed the aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ and it built my file just fine thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cc1plus` is the internal front end program name for the Gnu Compiler Collection's C++ compiler. It's being called in this case because `gcc` has detected that `test.cpp` is a C++ file rather than a C file.

You would get it by installing the corresponding g++ package for the C compiler that you are using. For the `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` cross compiler, that would be [g++-aarch64-linux-gnu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/g++-aarch64-linux-gnu) I think.

You should then use `aarch64-linux-gnu-g++` to compile your `.cpp` sources.

Comment: Thank you that's correct.